# Docker compose volumes in nodejs microservices application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

When make volumes in docker-compose.yml and run docker-compose up and in "yarn run" step, it says (error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/usr/src/app")

my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn
COPY . .
CMD [ "yarn", "watch" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    listings-service:
        build: ./listings-service
        volumes:
            - ./listings-service:/usr/src/app
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "listings-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "babel-watch -L ./index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the sequence runs `yarn run`?  Does it work if you delete the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file to run the actual code that's being built into the image?  (Your `volumes:` will hide the `package.json` that gets `COPY`ed in line 4 of the `Dockerfile`, which could cause this error.)

Comment: For the first question may be run watch 
For the second one yes it works when I remove volumes
Exactly what you say so, what can I do ? and why it hides the package.json file @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

why do you need the volume here? your docker files compy all the files in and place them inside the docker image. In addition, running `yarn` will install dependencies and place them in `/usr/src/app`.

Adding the volume on the docker-compose ==> all files from the docker image will be removed and placed with the files inside the local path `./listings-service`

Comment: I need the volume for listening to local changes ... so that if I change a local file it will be updated in the image, or what is the right way for doing that? @Al-waleed Shihadeh